# Where to find editors to hire for tech blog?

Tags: editing

Recently, I secured a job with big MNC. Now, I want to concentrate on it and appoint 2-3 editors to look after mildly popular tech blog.

Can you guys suggest where should I search or post to hire part-time/full-time editors?

Comment: try posting ads in local newspapers, ask in job agencies or on job search web-sites. Explore more in friends or networks

Comment: There are several users who frequent this site who are editors. Some of them have experience editing blogs and can be contacted via their profiles. *cough cough*

Comment: +1 to @NeilFein :) 

I'm also interested in knowing more, could you share your contact details either here or in your profile?

Comment: Rather than offering a single link/website, a good answer to this question will explain the general process of locating, selecting, and hiring editors.

Comment: Have protected this question for now, since it's attracting a lot of brief answers when what it really needs is a canonical answer explaining the process of finding editors and maybe the issues involved. Is anyone willing to tackle this?

Comment: @NeilFein Done.

Answer (score 2):

From what you have so far stated in the question you already have the resource but have not yet utilized it. On every forum you will have multiple users who  are avidly active posting on blogs giving their opinions and in general helping the community off their own backs. The problem with hiring freelance people is that they would be coming onto your blog without knowing what it’s all about. By trying to find an already present user that has contributed to the blog, they already know what you, the MNC and the blog are trying to achieve. Consider creating a separate part on the blog or even a blog post advertising that you require a few part time blog editors and try find a few examples of [blog job requirements](http://jobs.problogger.net/view/6708) and look for crucial parts that you need and tailor it to that.

Answer (score 0):

If it's mildly popular, and you are looking to pay editors, you might be better off concentrating your funds to pay just one editor. Writers are often pretty reliable, so one should be plenty.

If there are any repeat commenters or authors in your community, the best (and cheapest) option is to crowdsource this. i.e., get one or more volunteers. Make it worth their while by giving them some extra perks and swag, and they can make an impact by helping your community.

Answer (score 0):

There are several job boards particularly aimed at experienced bloggers, editors, and other on-line content workers. Sites like [Problogger have job boards](http://jobs.problogger.net/) focused on this kind of role. You might also consider writing/editing-heavy freelancing boards like [FreelanceSwitch.](http://jobs.freelanceswitch.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Try www.elance.com or www.guru.com

These sites are technically for individual jobs, but it would give you a chance to give potential editors a test run.

Answer (score -1):

For specific roles, try posting on forums that tech savvy people are likely to frequent.

Comment: I'm not sure it helps the OP, and isn't it what the OP tried to do here?